# Need a IRF540 Gate Driver Circuit for 5 Level Packed U Cell Inverter

Tags: inverter, mosfet-driver, esp32

I am trying to design a 5 level packed U cell inverter for dynamic wireless charging application using level shifted PWM technique.

I understand that I need a gate driver to operate my MOSFET along with ESP 32 or Arduino Uno microcontroller. My inverter should operate at 13 kHz output frequency and 24 V supply. I have generated PWM pulses and learning to design gate driver. (I am a student and currently working on my project. Correct me if  I am wrong). Does anybody knows how would I design a gate driver circuit?

Comment: You need to give us more details, especially a schematic of your circuit so far. The more detail we have, the easier it will be to address your specific problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have developed pwm signals using matlab simulink and arduino. Firstly I tried to drive the mosfet directly from arduino without using any gate driver circuit. Currently I am planning to try out IR2110 driver IC along with a gate resistor. I dont know how exactly should I design Gate drive circuit and select components for different Voltage and Frequency parameters.